# Unable to load div with external Url

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am using asp.net MVC 5 application. In that, I am using the jquery to load the div with the external url.

**Html**

```
<div id="DivOne" class="oddNum">Div One</div>
<button id="btnOne">Load Content</button>
```

**Jquery**

```
$('#btnOne').click(function() {
    // Action goes here
    $('#DivOne').load('http://www.artisteer.com');
});
```

I am getting the following error message (in browser console) when in button click event.

Failed to load http://www.artisteer.com/: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. 
Origin 'http://fiddle.jshell.net' is therefore not allowed access.

Here is the JsFiddle Url:
http://jsfiddle.net/Q8KVC/7533/

**Note:** I dont want to use iframe

**PS:** Okay, I think I am left with only option is to use iframes. Do we get the same issue with the iframes as well?

Comment: try to use it in iframe.

Comment: sorry, I don't want to use iframe

Comment: .load() does in fact a GET and you can't make an ajax request to an external domain because of CORS unless the external domain allows it

Comment: @Pearl if artisteer.com is your domain then allow the cors, else ask the honor of domain to allow it for you. from this end you can not allow the cors.

Comment: @Aay Que, its not my domain. I want to show the list of external websites (third party sites like google, sony, apple, etc) using this approach.

Comment: @Pearl I dont think there is any option available to resolve the issue except using Iframe.

Comment: @ Aay Que Okay, Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use an https endpoint for your external URL, otherwise, you will end up with a mixed content error on console

you can see visit link for  more understanding 
[mixed-content-the-page-was-loaded-over-https-but-requested-an-insecure-xmlhttprequest-endpoint](https://discuss.emberjs.com/t/mixed-content-the-page-was-loaded-over-https-but-requested-an-insecure-xmlhttprequest-endpoint/13876/3)

- HTTPS is important to protect both your site and your users from
  attack.
- Mixed content degrades the security and user experience of your HTTPS
  site.

Answer (score 0):

For chrome if add `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` plugin it will solve the issue. It will work for chrome browser only